# Perl: Is it possible to iterate over an anonymous hash?

Tags: perl, hash, foreach, anonymous-types

It's easy enough to iterate over a list:

```
foreach my $elem ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ) {
  say $elem;
}
```

or an anonymous array:

```
foreach my $elem (@{[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]}) {
  say $elem;
}
```

But is it possible to do the same for an anonymous hash?  I tried:

```
while (my ($key, $value) = each (%{{ a => 1, b => 2, c => 3 }})) {
  say "$key=$value";
}
```

but I get an infinite loop.

Comment: Contrary to what you said, there is no array involved in `foreach my $elem ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ) {
  say $elem;
}`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A foreach loop evaluates its expression once. `while`, on the other hand, evaluates its expression once each pass. That means you are repeatedly creating a new hash and grabbing its first element.

You could do the following:

```
use List::Util 1.29 qw( pairs );

for my $pair ( pairs %{ { a => 1, b => 2, c => 3 } } ) {
   my ( $key, $val ) = @$pair;
   ...
}
```

But just like your second snippet is a needlessly wasteful and complex version of your first snippet, the above is a needlessly wasteful and complex version of the following:

```
use List::Util 1.29 qw( pairs );

for my $pair ( pairs a => 1, b => 2, c => 3 ) {
   my ( $key, $val ) = @$pair;
   ...
}
```

Comment: Anything you see wrong with `foreach my $key (keys %{...})`  No need to `use` for `keys`, right?

Comment: @stevesliva, There's no way of accessing the values if you do that.

Comment: Ha, yeah.  I wasn't thinking past the iteration part!  Oh, of course, you want the answer to be *useful*, too?

Comment: @stevesliva, In that case, have you considered `for (1..keys(%{ ... }))`? :)